# Using ReactRouterDOM with HashRouter in a dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using [`withRouter()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to transform a dropdown menu in a router.
Unfortunately, I need to use hashed routes.

Is there a similar approach that can be used with [`HashRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter). 
Thank you.

UPDATE:

This is the relevant source in `main.js`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      React.createElement(ReactRouterDOM.BrowserRouter, null,
        React.createElement("div", null,
        // ...

        React.createElement(ReactRouterDOM.withRouter(Dropdown), {
          _value: this.state.foo,
          _options: [this.state.foo],
          _onChangeCallback: this.handleChangeCallback  // this updates the state
        }),
        // ...

        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

In `dropdown.js` the component changes the route accordingly with the dropdown:

```js
export default class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  // ...

  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.props._value) this.props.history.push(`/${this.props._value}`);  // update route
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.props._onChangeCallback(event.target.value);  // update the state
  }
  // ...

    render() {
        const options = this.props._options.map((val) => React.createElement("option", {value: val}, val));

        return React.createElement("div", null,
            React.createElement("span", null,
                React.createElement("select", {
                    onChange: this.handleChange,
                    value: this.props._value,
                }, options)));
    }
}
```

When the component mounts there is an HTTP request to fetch some data;
The fetched data is saved into the state and the dropdown menu updates;
When the option changes the route changes as well.

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample to something you've tried to do?

Comment: @DorShinar I updated the question, thank you.

Comment: @DorShinar I hardcoded the hash in the path (`this.props.history.push(\`/#/${this.props._value}\`);`) and it seems to work. Thank you anyway.